# Why selenium is run in headless mode if a slave connected via SSH?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, ssh, selenium-chromedriver

I use Jenkins to run tests and connect a slave to it.

Before I connected the slave using Java application and when I started build the tests were run visibly - I saw browser windows opening on the slave.

**Now I connect the same slave but using SSH** and when I start build **the tests are run but they run in headless mode** so I don't see anything going on the slave (only in processes).

I want to see the process of tests execution as I saw it when my slave was connected using Java.

I use ChromeDriver to run tets.

Any ideas and explanations why this happened when I changed the way of connection?

Comment: Did you get the solution. even i have recently installed the jenkins on windows machine and staring executing my test it executing all test in headless mode

Answer (score 0):

When slave connected with SSH, browser being launched by Jenkins user (or local system on windows), so you can't see it because you logged in with another account.

When you start the slave with Java Web Start it uses your account so you can see what's happening.

Comment: Okay so if my slave works on Windows 7 how can I see what is going on? I need to log in with a correct user?

Comment: Change Log On As property of Jenkins service. Check Allow to interact with desktop or use your account

Comment: it didn't help. Can you suggest more ideas?