# Installed JNLP connect as windows service, but on running my selenium jobs it is running on back ground without opening browser physically

Tags: jnlp

Installed JNLP connect as windows service, but on running my selenium jobs it is running on back ground without opening browser physically. I need browser to be opened to run my test cases

Comment: Does this answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35939326/366965

Comment: It didnt help, any other ideas?